# Partial templates are not able to connect to the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

[command promt error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvlVL.png)In home.html, the value of {{message}} is not displayed .Infact it displays {{message}}

node.js is used to run the application.I guess there is a problem in connecting to the controller or the server.Please help to find the solution.

```js
var app=angular.module('Demo',["ngRoute"])
.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider)
 {
  $routeProvider
   .when("/home",{
    templateUrl:"home.html",
    controller:"homeController"
   })
   
   .otherwise({
        template : "<h1>None</h1><p>Nothing has been selected</p>"
    })
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

 })
 .controller("homeController",function($scope)
 {
  $scope.message="hey home page";
 })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html >
<head>
<title>angular</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="router.js"></script>
<base href="./" />
</head>
<body ng-app="Demo">
<div>
<h1>website header</h1>
</div>
<div>
 <ul>
  <a href="home"><li>home</li></a>
  
  
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="mainContent">
 <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
<h1>footer</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<h1>{{message}}</h1>
<div>
message from controller will be displayed here
</div>
```

Comment: There are any errors in developer console?

Comment: There is error in command prompt:-angular is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this `<a href="#home"><li>home</li></a>` Maybe you missed the `#`in the `a` tag

Comment: No,that is removed deliberately